# Handle object in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, handle, void-pointers

I've been told that a handle is a sort of "void" pointer. But what exactly does "void pointer" mean and what is its purpose. Also, what does `"somehandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);` do?

Comment: You mean a Windows API `HANDLE` rather than handles in general?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A handle in the general sense is an opaque value that uniquely identifies an object. In this context, "opaque" means that the entity distributing the handle (e.g. the window manager) knows how handles map to objects but the entities which use the handle (e.g. your code) do not.

This is done so that they cannot get at the real object unless the provider is involved, which allows the provider to be sure that noone is messing with the objects it owns behind its back.

Since it's very practical, handles have traditionally been integer types or `void*` because using primitives is much easier in C than anything else. In particular, a lot of functions in the Win32 API accept or return handles (which are `#define`d with various names: `HANDLE`, `HKEY`, many others). All of these types map to `void*`.

**Update:**

To answer the second question (although it might be better asked and answered on its own):

`GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)` [returns a handle to the standard input device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can use this handle to read from your process's standard input.

Comment: Ok. Because I have been doing some keyboard and mouse imput type things, but I feel kind of lost without knowing what a handle is. So it is a value that essentially points to something that only the window knows?

Comment: Good answer.  I would simply add that the fact they map to `void*` is simply how they are implemented in some version of Windows.  It could change in a later version (though it probably won't), and it isn't really important.  You should think of the `HANDLE` types as simply a unique identifier and leave it at that.  You aren't supposed to know anything else about them.

Comment: Is it used as a reference point then? For the function to manipulate and use however it wants?

Comment: @someguy: It "points to" something that only the kernel (of which the window manager is a subsystem) knows how to get to. I would prefer the verb "identifies" instead of "points to" because when talking about C, "point" is a word that carries strong connotations. The `HANDLE` *is* actually a pointer, but using it as such goes against the very reason we go to this trouble in the first place. Don't do it.

Comment: Just to clarify in case it makes a difference, I'm using c++.

Comment: @someguy: Doesn't make a difference when talking about handles.

Comment: Ok. So I think I understand what a handle is now. But why can't the kernel or the subsystem or whatever provide that handle on its own

Comment: A very good answer.  I might add that the value of a handle is sometimes referred to as a magic cookie.  (I don't know where the name comes from, but in the past, I've heard it a lot.)

Comment: @someguy: what do you mean? The handles *are* provided by the kernel or whatever part of the OS you are interacting with...

Comment: Ok then why do you need to write HANDLE handle

Comment: @Kieren: Updated the answer, although I think it's not productive to bunch unrelated questions together (this is one reason why I did not answer it initially).

Comment: @someguy: because you need some place to store such value?

Answer (score 4):

A `HANDLE` isn't necessarily a pointer or a double pointer, it may be an index in an OS table as well as anything else. It's defined for convenience as a `void *` because *often* is used actually as a pointer, and because in C `void *` is a type on which you can't perform almost any operation.

The key point is that you must think at it as some opaque token that represents a resource managed by the OS; passing it to the appropriate functions you tell them to operate on such object. Because it's "opaque", you shouldn't change it or try to dereference it: just use it with functions that can work with it.

Answer (score 0):

A `HANDLE` is a pointer to a pointer, it's pretty much as simple as that.

So to get the pointer to the data, you'd have to dereference it first.

`GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)` will return the handle to the stdin stream - standard input.  That's either the console or a file/stream if you invoke from the command prompt with a '<' character.

Comment: HANDLE is defined as void * in winnt.h, not as a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Ok Thanks. That makes more sense. So it is pretty much a NULL pointer

Comment: A handle in the general sense is an opaque identifier. Therefore, a `HANDLE` (specific case) should definitely *not* be thought of as a pointer to anything, for the C definition of "pointer".

Comment: Ok. Because I have been doing some keyboard and mouse imput type things, but I feel kind of lost without knowing what a handle is. So it is a value that essentially points to something that only the window knows?

Comment: Is it used as a reference point then? For the function to manipulate and use however it wants?

Answer (score 0):

A Windows `HANDLE` is effectively an index into an array of void pointers, plus a few other things. A void pointer (`void*`) is the pointer that points to an unknown type and should be avoided at all costs in C++- however the Windows API is C-compatible and uses it to avoid having to expose Windows internal types.

`GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)` means, get the `HANDLE` associated to the Standard output stream.

Comment: Ok. So what is meant in the previous answer by a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: The whole point about `HANDLE` is that it isn't an index into an array of anything. It is simply an opaque pimpl type. Yes, the underlying implementation that is in use today might be known, but it could change completely tomorrow.

Comment: Ok. Because I have been doing some keyboard and mouse imput type things, but I feel kind of lost without knowing what a handle is. So it is a value that essentially points to something that only the window knows?

Comment: You mean, the standard *input* stream. Duh.

Comment: Is it used as a reference point then? For the function to manipulate and use however it wants?